# Delete one to one chat history messages programmatically in Quickblox?

Tags: ios, quickblox

In my testing chat app (made with QuickBlox iOS SDK), I'm creating a one-to-one chat dialogue between test users (given in QuickBlox Chat Sample for iOS).

Now I tested it well, and I wants to delete all of my messages at once?

Is it possible? if Yes, then how?

I read about this method, but I guess, that's for individual messages and not entire conversation.

```
+ (NSObject<Cancelable> *)deleteMessageWithID:(NSString *)messageID delegate:(NSObject<QBActionStatusDelegate> *)delegate;
+ (NSObject<Cancelable> *)deleteMessageWithID:(NSString *)messageID delegate:(NSObject<QBActionStatusDelegate> *)delegate context:(void *)context;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to delete a dialog

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Delete_dialog